# How do we implement %* in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

When I try to execute %* inside batch script by using powershell, it gives me an error. I need something to be replaced for `%*` so that it works for the following code snippet:

```
%* ^| ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ ; $filepath = 'loggerfile.log' ; $output_file =$(Get-Date).ToString() + ' ' + $_ ; Write-Output $output_file ^|  Out-File -FilePath $filepath  -Append -NoClobber}
```

Comment: so you want to loop through all files in the arguments?

Comment: You don't need to escape the pipeline in powershell. If it's a true Powershell ps1.

Comment: !. What you have is syntactically not valid, and 2. not a real one-liner. That semicolon is a code terminator. The left side is completely independent of the right. `%` is a linas for `ForEach-Object`. Be sure to lookup PowerShell automatic variables, and PowerShell special characters. They cannot be used for anything else.

Comment: What do you mean by _"When I try to execute %* inside powershell script"_? `%*` is not something you can execute, it is a definition of all the input paramaters sent from somewhere. I feel you are not showing us everything we need to know here. Why the `batch-file` tag? are you executing `powershell` from a batch file?

Comment: This code looks like you are coming from another language, and trying to use constructs from that mixed with PowerShell, in a faux one-liner. That's not a thing. Well, that, or you are misunderstanding how to use the pipeline and true one-liners vs all code on the same line.

Comment: So you want `$args |...`?

Comment: @Gerhard Yes, I'm using this code inside a batch-file so I have ^| pipes inside the script.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen pretty much what OP wants, the difference is that stdin is supposed to be sent via batch-file, hence my comment to OP in the comment requesting clarification as that was what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

First, know why this is not valid code:

```
%* $| ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ ; $filepath = 'loggerfile.log' ; $output_file =$(Get-Date).ToString() + ' ' + $_ ; Write-Output $output_file ^|  Out-File -FilePath $filepath  -Append -NoClobber}

Get-Alias -Definition ForEach-Object | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
CommandType Name                      Version Source
----------- ----                      ------- ------
Alias       % -> ForEach-Object                     
Alias       foreach -> ForEach-Object  
#>
```

This is why you get...

```
%*
%*: The term '%*' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

... when you use it.

And this ...

```
^
```

... is a termination character

Second, as well as your code is not a one-liner, as I commented above. What you really have is this...

```
ForEach-Object '*' ^| 
ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Host $PSItem 
    $filepath    = 'loggerfile.log'
    $output_file = $(Get-Date).ToString() + ' ' + $PSItem

    Write-Output $output_file ^|  
    Out-File -FilePath $filepath  -Append -NoClobber
}
```

... and this.

```
ForEach-Object '*' ^
```

is not valid at all. I am curious as to where you got that from. As well as this...

```
^|
```

... as that is not a thing I've ever seen in any PowerShell docs, help files, repo code. This is also not aliases for anything natively.

Did you mean to do this...

```
$^
```

which means - The first token of the last command. Note though, it 'Does NOT' refer to the whole command.

The `|` pipe is of course pass results from the left of it to the right of it. What are you expecting this...

```
ForEach-Object '*' ^|
```

...to do? Even if you did, that is not valid and would error off with.

```
ForEach-Object: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

So, did you mean to do this...

```
%* $^
```

... which is still something I've never seen in 10+ years I've been messing with Monad/Windows PowerShell/PowerShell Core.

To know what your code is doing, you take two steps.

1. Use PSSCriptANalyzer to validate what you are doing according to the PowerShell ruleset

   Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer "$PWD\SomeScriptName.ps1"
2. Trace the execution, so you can see the stack.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command?view=powershell-7.1

```
Trace-Command -Name metadata,parameterbinding,cmdlet -Expression {
%* ^| ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ ; $filepath = 'loggerfile.log' ; $output_file =$(Get-Date).ToString() + ' ' + $_ ; Write-Output $output_file ^|  Out-File -FilePath $filepath  -Append -NoClobber}
} -PSHost
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'm trying to mimic a shell script. I'm using this code inside a batch file so I used ^| to pipe through powershell. Also here's my equivalent code of shell script : $* | while read line; do echo $line; echo "$(date) $line" >> something.log; done